# Output on same form in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to search employee list depend on area name which is selected from dropdown list. I can retrieve names of areas from database into dropdown list from PHP HTML. But now I am confused how to pass selected option in dropdown list to SQL query in PHP. Also I want index numbers of selected options. My code is as follows.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'Connect.php';
$query = "SELECT varAreaName FROM tbArea" ;
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo'<select name="somename">';
echo'<option value="ANY">--ANY--</option>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) { 
    echo '<option value="'.$row['varAreaName'].'">' . $row['varAreaName'] . '</option>';   
}
echo '</select>';                
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I want the output on same form using Javascript. But I am new in JavaScript. Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: Come on shouters, it's time shout out as "don't use mysql_* funcs anymore"...

Comment: You will need to POST the selected item in a form or use ajax to send the data to a PHP script.
Also while mysql_xxxx functions will be disappearing it will be quite some time before they eventually disappear so don't worry about the php grammar police just yet.

Comment: @qeremy What's wrong with offering simple advice like that? Most people don't read the docs thoroughly, and it's easily missed. Interested to hear your argument against commenting about their use??

Comment: No, it just annoying to hear it all the time recursively. And, if any programmer does not read or track the manual properly, this is his problem...

Comment: Half of the problems on SO are cases of RTFM. I'd leave now if you're easily offended by that sort of thing :P

Comment: @qeremy If that was the case then every programmer would have switched to MySQLi when PHP 4 came out, and subsequently to PDO when PHP 5 came out. Most people do not follow the docs until things become deprecated.

Comment: @qeremy It's also annoying to have to close all these sql injection holes again and again and again, typing out function names like `mysql_real_bla_bla_bla_bla`. The sooner people switch to prepared statements, the better.

Comment: @qeremy It's only repetitive from "our" (meaning us people constantly crawling SO) perspective. Seldom for the question asker.

Comment: OK gangs, so mission completed and there is no reason to shout anymore, right? :))

Answer (score 1):

You might want to learn about AJAX for this. Dynamically altering the page from the database using javascript is only possible when there's another script performing the server side operation (in this case, the database query).

This should get you going in the direction. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Also, obligatory - Please don't use MySQL as it is deprecated and not maintained by PHP any more. Use MySQLi, or PDO.